# Using Task.Run for synchronous method in service

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I've read a lot of articles about asynchronnous programming, but I'm not sure in one thing. I have 3rd party winrt library, written in C++ and I want to wrapp it. So now I have:

```
public Task LoginAsync(){
return Task.Run(winrtLibrary.Login();)
}
```

According Stephen Cleary and Stephen Toub blogs, it is not good solution. But when I use the method synchronously, my UI will not be responsive and will be blocked.
Is it better to expose service method synchronously and in UI use Task.Run?

Comment: What does that method do ? Something long that block your UI ? Then the answer is yes, start it in a new task.

Comment: Yes, Login method can be long running. It depends on network etc. If I block the UI, I cannot cancel login process.

Comment: The point that Stephen Cleary made is that `Task.Run` "wastes" a Thread to do work, and Threads are expensive. However your C++ library REQUIRES a Thread to work. So the problem isn't so much that `Task.Run` is evil. But `Task.Run` typically hides the problem of relying on threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Stephen Toub means by

> do not use Task.Run in the implementation of the method; instead, use Task.Run to call the method

Is that you shouldn't use `Task.Run` to hide CPU bound work behind async methods (`Task` returning methods). If you need to wrap external code, hide it behind an interface which reflects what this code do. Any asynchronous I/O can (and should) be exposed as `Task` returning methods, and CPU bound work must be exposed with the proper API. Let the consumers of your code to decide for themselves how to use that code. When you happen to by the consumer too, use `Task.Run` to run your synchronous code (now wrapped and exposed via interface) **where it is very clear that you are offloading CPU bound work**. In UI apps, for example, you should call `Task.Run` in your UI layer (and not deep down in your BL or even DA layers), where it is very clear that the UI offloads some CPU bound work.

---

> Why do you think, that I shouldn't call Task.Run in BL? What if I have
>   ViewModel, which references BL and BL references service layer (in my
>   case is it wrapper).

I think that a method signature should reflect exactly what the method does. 
The best I can do is to redirect you back to [Cleary's article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html):

> When a developer sees two methods in an API winrtLibrary.Login() and winrtLibrary.LoginAsync(), **the convention is that they represent a naturally-asynchronous
>   operation**. In other words, the developer expects that winrtLibrary.LoginAsync() is
>   the “natural” implementation and that winrtLibrary.Login() is essentially a
>   synchronous (blocking) equivalent of that operation. That API implies
>   that winrtLibrary.Login will at some point have the calling thread enter a wait
>   state as it blocks for the naturally-asynchronous operation to
>   complete.

You can still hide synchronous code behind async method and follow Cleary's rule of thumb, if you sign your method as `public Task OffloadLoginToTheThreadPool()`. But I think (and apparently Cleary, too) that the alternative of simply calling `Task.Run` from the UI (or Controller) is a much better approach, and it follows the principles of Clean Code.

Comment: Why do you think, that I shouldn't call Task.Run in BL? What if I have ViewModel, which references BL and BL references service layer (in my case is it wrapper).